# Posicionar hacia enfrente todo al llamar otra hoja de HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema con este código:

```html
<body>
  <?php include "header.php"; ?>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/neko/ccs/index.css">
  <center>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="margin-top: 5%;height: auto;width: 80%;margin-left: -2%;">
      <?php
      include "conexion.php";
      $sql_slider = mysqli_query($enlace, "SELECT * from promociones");
      $nums_slides = mysqli_num_rows($sql_slider);
      for ($i = 0; $i < $nums_slides; $i++) {
          $active = "active"; ?>
          <span data-target="#carousel-example-captions" data-slide-to="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="<?php echo $active; ?>"></span>
          <?php $active = "";
      }
      ?>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php
        $active = "active";
        while ($rw_slider = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_slider)) { ?>
          <div class="item <?php echo $active; ?>"> 
            <?php echo "<a href='/neko/usuarios/productos.php?ref=" .
                $rw_slider["direccion"] .
                "'>"; ?><img src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(
$rw_slider["imagen"]
); ?>" data-holder-rendered="true"style="height:350px">
            <div class="carousel-caption"> 
            </div> 
          </div>
          <?php $active = "";}
        $enlace->close();
        ?>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </center>
  <?php include "footer.php"; ?>
</body>
```

Lo que pasa es que tengo una función en 'header' que hace que se ponga una cortina gris y hace unos efectos, pero tengo el problema de que al poner esa cortina, todo lo que tengo en este código y el 'footer' queda por delante de la cortina que tengo en header, entonces me gustaría saber cómo hacer que todo quede por atrás de esa cortina que tengo en header. He intentado con `z-index` y con `position:absolute` y sigue poniéndose por atrás de footer y este código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no se si te va a servir pero fijate de ponerle z-index a center también, que el valor sea menos que el de header y lo mismo con el footer, no estas mostrando todo el código completo, por ahí estoy hablando al pedo